# What is the difference between these 2 programs, one in C and the other in PIC assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, pic

I have written/copied/modified an I2C client written in C which works.  When I translate it to assembly language it fails.  Where am I going wrong?

The master/slave design is very simple.  Master sends an integer value to the slave.  Slave flashes an LED to show the value received then increments the value and sends it back to master.
When I run the C language slave version it works as expected.  When I run the assembly version, the interrupt is not driven and I observe no activity (no LED flashes) on the slave.
I will post the C code and the corresponding assembly code to see if anyone can see why the assembly version is not working

Here is the C code

```
/* 
 * File:   slave.c
 * Author: mike
 *
 * Created on 18 March 2024, 2:32 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*

                                     PIC16F1503
                              +----------:_:----------+
                    +5V <>  1 : VDD               VSS : 14 <> GND
            RED LED o/p <>  2 : RA5               RA0 : 13 <> 
                        <>  3 : RA4               RA1 : 12 <> 
                        <>  4 : RA3/MCLR          RA2 : 11 <>      
                        <>  5 : RC5               RC0 : 10 <> SCL (input)
                        <>  6 : RC4               RC1 : 9  <> SDA (input) 
                        <>  7 : RC3               RC2 : 8  <> RED LED o/p
                              +-----------------------+
                                       DIP-14
 
 */
// PIC16F1503 Configuration Bit Settings

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)

// Set Clock Freq. & Delays
#define _XTAL_FREQ  16000000      // oscillator frequency for _delay()

#include <xc.h>

#define slaveAddress 0x60
// Set Clock Freq. & Delays
#define _XTAL_FREQ  16000000      // oscillator frequency for _delay()

#define testBit(var, bit)   (var & (1 << bit))
#define clearBit(var, bit)  (var ^= (1 << bit))
#define setBit(var, bit)    (var |= (1 << bit))

uint8_t temp, flagWord;
#define dataReceived 0

void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{
    if (PIR1bits.SSP1IF || PIR2bits.BCL1IF) {
        //Check for SSPIF
        if(PIR1bits.SSP1IF) {
            if (SSP1STATbits.P) { // Stop bit: 1 = stop detected
                //Stop Condition
                // do nothing
                ;
            }
            else if(SSP1STATbits.R_nW) { // R/W bit: 1 = read, 0 = write
                //Host wants to read (client transmit)
                // increment value in temp and send to master
                temp+=1;        // increment temp and return to master
                SSP1BUF = temp;
            }   
            else {  
                // Host wants to write (client receive)
                if(SSP1STATbits.D_nA) { // Data/Address: 1 = data, 0 = address
                    //Last byte was data
                    temp = SSP1BUF;
                    setBit(flagWord, dataReceived);
                }
                else {
                    //Last byte was an address
                    //Clear the Buffer Full (BF) flag
                    temp = SSP1BUF;
                }
            }
        }
        if(PIR2bits.BCL1IF) {
            //Clear the Buffer Full (BF) flag
            temp = SSP1BUF;

            // Clear BCLIF
            PIR2bits.BCL1IF = 0;
        }
    
        //Release Clock Stretch
        SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 1;

        //Clear SSP1IF
        PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    }
}

void flashLEDMultiple(uint8_t count) {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        // turn LED on
        LATA5 = 1;
        __delay_ms(200);
        LATA5 = 0;
        if (i+1<count) {
            __delay_ms(200);
        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    
    OSCCON = 0B01111000;        // set oscillator to 16MHz
    
    //Init the I2C Pins on the Device
    // RA0 = SCL, RA1 = SDA
    // RC0 = SCL, RC1 = SDA
    
    //Disable analog mode
    ANSELA = 0;     // all PORTA pins digital
    ANSELC = 0;     // all PORTC pins digital
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0b1;
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0b1;
    
    TRISAbits.TRISA5 = 0;   // output for LED
    LATAbits.LATA5 = 0;     // LED off
    
    //Initialize the I2C Driver
    //Reset Registers
    SSP1CON1 = 0x00;
    SSP1CON2 = 0x00;
    SSP1CON3 = 0x00;
    SSP1STAT = 0x00;
         
    SSP1STATbits.SMP = 1;   //Disable slew control for Standard mode
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM = 0b0110; //Set MSSP Operating Mode (7-bit Client)
    SSP1CON2bits.SEN = 1;   //Enable clock stretching
    SSP1CON3bits.SBCDE = 1; //Enable bus collision interrupts
    SSP1ADD = (unsigned char)(slaveAddress << 1);   //Load slave address
    PIR2bits.BCL1IF = 0;    //Clear Bus Collision interrupt flag
    PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0;    //Clear the SSP interrupt flag
    PIE2bits.BCL1IE = 1;    //Enable BCLIF
    PIE1bits.SSP1IE = 1;    //Enable SSPIF
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 1; //Enable the module
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;    // Enable peripheral interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;     // Enable global interrupts                                                         
    
    while (1)
    {
        if (testBit(flagWord,dataReceived)) {
            clearBit(flagWord,dataReceived);
            flashLEDMultiple(temp); // flash the received count value
        }
    }
    
    return;
}
```

and here is the 'identical?' assembly code (which doesn't work)

```
; Slave: Sample code to demonstrate use of the MSSP module to drive 
;    slave device via I2C
; Author:   Mike Brady
; Company:  Java Point Pty Ltd
;
;   Pin summary
;   1   VDD +3.3V
;   8   RC2 Red LED
;      14   VSS Ground
;    
;  Assembled with pic-as (v2.32) under MPLAB X IDE (v6.15) 4 Mar 2024
;
; Add this line in the project properties box, pic-as Global Options -> Additional options: 
;   -Wa,-a -Wl,-pPOR_Vec=0h,-pISR_Vec=4h
;
;
;                                     PIC16F1503
;                              +----------:_:----------+
;                    +5V <>  1 : VDD               VSS : 14 <> GND
;            RED LED o/p <>  2 : RA5               RA0 : 13 <> 
;                    <>  3 : RA4               RA1 : 12 <> 
;                        <>  4 : RA3/MCLR          RA2 : 11 <>      
;                        <>  5 : RC5               RC0 : 10 <> SCL (input)
;                        <>  6 : RC4               RC1 : 9  <> SDA (input) 
;                        <>  7 : RC3               RC2 : 8  <> 
;                              +-----------------------+
;                                       DIP-14
;    
    
PAGEWIDTH   132
RADIX       DEC

#include <xc.inc>

; See respective data sheet for additional information on configuration word.
config FOSC = INTOSC    ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
config WDTE = OFF       ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
config PWRTE = OFF      ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (Power-up Timer is disabled)
config CP = OFF         ; Code Protection bit (Code protection disabled)
config MCLRE = ON
config BOREN = ON
config CLKOUTEN = OFF
config WRT = OFF
config STVREN = OFF
config LVP = OFF
config LPBOR = OFF
config BORV = LO
    
; vars used by TimerLib library
global      d1,d2,d3
extrn       delay5us

    
#define FOSC        16000   ; Oscillator Clock in kHz    
                
#define dataReceived 0
    
//I2C Test Properties
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x60  ; unique address for this slave
    
;**********************************************************************
; Power-On-Reset entry point
;**********************************************************************
PSECT POR_Vec,global,class=CODE,delta=2
    global  resetVec
resetVec:
    goto    main

;objects in Common RAM - address 70h
psect udata_shr,global,class=COMMON,space=1,delta=1,noexec
    d1:         DS  1
    d2:         DS  1
    d3:         DS  1
    flagWord:       DS  1
    bufferValue:    DS  1
    flashCounter:   DS  1
    
;**********************************************************************
; Interrupt vector and handler
;**********************************************************************
PSECT ISR_Vec,global,class=CODE,delta=2
    global  ISR_Vec
    
ISR_Vec:
    banksel PIR1
    btfsc   PIR1, PIR1_SSP1IF_POSN
    goto    SSP_or_BCL_set
    btfss   PIR2, PIR2_BCL1IF_POSN
    retfie
    
SSP_or_BCL_set:
    btfss   PIR1, PIR1_SSP1IF_POSN
    goto    checkBusCollision
    banksel SSP1STAT
    btfss   SSP1STAT, SSP1STAT_R_nW_POSN
    goto    masterSending
    incf    bufferValue,f
    movf    bufferValue,w
    movwf   SSP1BUF
    goto    checkBusCollision
    
masterSending:
    btfss   SSP1STAT, SSP1STAT_D_nA_POSN
    goto    processAddress
    movf    SSP1BUF     ; read value from buffer
    movwf   bufferValue ; store received value
    bsf     flagWord, dataReceived
    goto    checkBusCollision
    
processAddress:
    movf    SSP1BUF     ; clear the BF flag
    
checkBusCollision:
    banksel PIR2
    btfss   PIR2, PIR2_BCL1IF_POSN
    goto    clockRelease
    banksel SSP1BUF
    movf    SSP1BUF,w   ; clear the BF flag
    banksel PIR2
    bcf     PIR2, PIR2_BCL1IF_POSN
    
clockRelease:
    banksel SSP1CON1
    bsf     SSP1CON1, SSP1CON1_CKP_POSN
    banksel PIR1
    bcf PIR1, PIR1_SSP1IF_POSN
    retfie
    
END_ISR_Vec:

;PSECT MainCode,global,class=CODE,delta=2
psect code,global,class=CODE,delta=2
    
initialisation:    ; setup peripherals, start timer
    call    setupOscillator
    call    setupIOPins
    call    I2C_init
    return
   
setupOscillator:
    ; initialise internal oscillator to 16MHz
    banksel OSCCON
    movlw   01111000B       ; Int. osc. 16 MHz
    movwf   OSCCON 
    btfss   HFIOFR      ; Int. osc. running?
    goto    $-1         ; No, loop back
    btfss   HFIOFS      ; Osc. stable?
    goto    $-1         ; No, loop back.
    return

setupIOPins:  ; RA0 - SCL, RA1 = SDA
    banksel ANSELA
    clrf    ANSELA      ; all PORTA pins digital
    clrf    ANSELC      ; all PORTC pins digital

    ; set all PORTA pins as output
    banksel TRISA   
    clrf    TRISA       ; set all PORTA as output
    ; set RC0 and RC1 as input, the rest as output
    clrf    TRISC
    bsf     TRISC, TRISC_TRISC0_POSN
    bsf     TRISC, TRISC_TRISC1_POSN
    
    ; turn off LED
    bcf     LATA, LATA_LATA5_POSN
    return
  
I2C_init:
    ;Configure MSSP module for Slave Mode
    banksel SSP1CON1
    clrf    SSP1CON1
    clrf    SSP1CON2
    clrf    SSP1CON3
    clrf    SSP1STAT
    
    bsf     SSP1STAT, SSP1STAT_SMP_POSN ; Disable slew control for Standard mode
    movlw   00000110B   ; Set MSSP Operating Mode (7-bit Client)
    iorwf   SSP1CON1,f  
    bsf     SSP1CON2, SSP1CON2_SEN_POSN ; Enable clock stretching
    bsf     SSP1CON3, SSP1CON3_SBCDE_POSN ; Enable bus collision interrupts
    movlw   SLAVE_ADDRESS<<1
    movwf   SSP1ADD     ; Load slave address
    banksel PIR2
    bcf     PIR2, PIR2_BCL1IF_POSN  ; Clear Bus Collision interrupt flag
    bcf     PIR1, PIR1_SSP1IF_POSN  ; Clear the SSP interrupt flag
    banksel PIE2
    bsf     PIE2, PIE2_BCL1IE_POSN  ; Enable bus collision interrupt
    bsf     PIE1, PIE1_SSP1IE_POSN  ; Enable MSSP interrupt
    bsf     INTCON, INTCON_PEIE_POSN
    bsf     INTCON, INTCON_GIE_POSN
    
    return

;**********************************************************************
; main program
;**********************************************************************
main:
    call    initialisation
    
loop:
    btfss   flagWord, dataReceived
    goto    loop
    bcf     flagWord, dataReceived
    movf    bufferValue, w
    call    flashLEDMultiple
    goto    loop
    
flashLEDMultiple:
    movwf   flashCounter
    call    flashLED
    call    delay200ms
    decfsz  flashCounter, f
    goto    flashLEDMultiple
    return
    
flashLED:
    banksel LATA
    bsf     LATA, LATA_LATA5_POSN
    call    delay200ms
    bcf     LATA, LATA_LATA5_POSN
    return
    
delay200ms:
    movlw   0x6D
    movwf   d1
    movlw   0xBF
    movwf   d2
    movlw   0x02
    movwf   d3
delay200ms_0:
    decfsz  d1, f
    goto    $+2
    decfsz  d2, f
    goto    $+2
    decfsz  d3, f
    goto    delay200ms_0
    return
```

Obviously these 2 programs are NOT functionally equivalent, but I am struggling to see how they differ.
Hoping someone with better eyes can point out how they differ.

@Lundin the interrupt is not driven/called. I don't have a working debugger but I use LED flashes to show which parts of the code are being executed. I just haven't shown them in the published code.

@Erik Eidt the disassembled code looks pretty standard.  Apart from the bank selection, it goes straight into the flag testing for SSP1IF and BCL1IF. I've attached a screen snippet [Disassembled ISR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16NHf.jpg)

@Frankie_C The intent is to **always** set the CKP flag on exit **when SSP1IF interrupt has occurred** and I believe the code does this. The ISR address is set in the linker with the directive **-pISR_Vec=4h**.

Comment: "the interrupt is not driven" What does that mean? If you put a breakpoint inside the interrupt, you never end up there, or...?

Comment: Suggest you look at the compiler output for the C code.  Suspect that `void __interrupt() ISR(void)` does some extra magic.

Comment: Do not write that much code without testing the pieces. You should already know that you can receive interrupts and that you can flash lights before you try to put the two together and have to guess which one has an error.

Comment: Some hints, are you sure that the interrupt vector is set with your ISR address? Leaving the ISR handler in C you set `CKP = 1` and clear `SSP1IF`, in your assembly exist a condition to leave without perform those actions (next interrupts will be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

There were several errors in the assembly version.

1 - The most significant was that SSPEN was **not** being set.

2 - Next, the initialisation of SSP1ADD was invalid.  The expression I was using (movlw SLAVE_ADDRESS << 1) did **not** result in the address (0x60) being shifted left by 1 bit.  I have now replaced this with the following code

movlw SLAVE_ADDRESS

movwf SSP1ADD

lslf  SSP1ADD, f

3 - Finally, the read of the data from the buffer did not result in the value being stored in the WREG.

movf    SSP1BUF   ; read value from buffer

should have been

movf    SSP1BUF, w   ; read value from buffer